# Aggregation $size: Issue when FieldPath field name contains a number in the path

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I’m trying to get the size of an array so that I can use the number that it returns in a for loop. I’m using mongodb compass. I’m trying to use something like the projection below where 0 is an object inside of path and “here” is an array with 2 items.

```
$project
{
    “alias” : {$size : “$this.is.the.field.path.0.here”}
}
```

However, this keeps returning an array size of 0. It works fine for field paths that don’t contain a number in their path but returns 0 if the path does contain a number. Is there a way to properly get the correct size of the array here[ ] which has a size of 2?

Comment: Please post your document structure?

Answer (score 0):

Using [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-for-an-element-by-the-array-index-position) to specify an array index works in the query language, but not in aggregation.

For aggregation, use the [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#-arrayelemat--aggregation-) operator.

Also note from the [BSON specification](https://bsonspec.org/spec.html):

> Array - The document for an array is a normal BSON document with integer values for the keys, starting with 0 and continuing sequentially. For example, the array ['red', 'blue'] would be encoded as the document {'0': 'red', '1': 'blue'}. The keys must be in ascending numerical order.

If you have a document that has numeric keys starting at 0, it will be treated as an array.